# Update record when the data already exist in model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a view where the user can upload several files.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def FileUploadView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = CallgateUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
       fecha = datetime.date.today()
       if form.is_valid():
          for each in form.cleaned_data['archivo']:
              Callgate_Syni.objects.create(fecha=fecha,archivo=each)
          os.system('/home/pyc/DjangoProjects/tap_app/media/docs/callgate/envia.sh')
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/lista/')
    else:
       form = CallgateUploadForm()
    return render_to_response('callgateupload.html',
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Form:

```
class CallgateUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

      archivo = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=20, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)
      def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(CallgateUploadForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
         self.helper = FormHelper(self)
      class Meta:
            model = Callgate_Syni
```

In the same day the user can upload the same file several times, this create a duplicated records for the same file ("archivo"). How can avoid to insert the information of the already uploaded files.
Or if the file already exist update the records in the model and if the file is not exist insert the record.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Django QuerySet [update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) method.

The usage is simple as:

```
updated_values = {'archivo': archivo}
obj, created = Callgate_Syni.objects.update_or_create(fecha=fecha, defaults=updated_values)
if created: 
    print('The object was created')
else:
    print('The object was updated')
```

The keyword args are the filters to specify if the record exists or not, and the defaults parameter is a `filedname: fieldvalue` dictionary with the fields to update.

The return tuple have the object that was created or updated, and a flag to indicate if the object was created.

Comment: I get the error  **'manager' object has no attribute 'update_or_create'**, I try some workaround I find in the web, but I still get that error. To use your aproach I nned to import some library?. or this is an error of my app settings

Comment: No library is required, it's Django built-in class. What is your Django version?

Answer (score 1):

From the description and `for each in form.cleaned_data['archivo']:` I understand what your want is:

- If all of the files are new, just save and create;
- If some of the files already exist, update them and insert the new files.

So you might want to give a date flag to the filenames so that you can check if the file already exists for a specific date and filename. For example, `sample_file_20160125.csv` will indicate a file named 'sample_file.csv' has already been uploaded by the user on 01/25/2016. Then you can match such a file in database, if found, update the file object; if not found, create a new record.

If you just want to save the file and not touch the database when the file is already there, use `exists()` to check if the record in the database.

```
...
if not Callgate_Syni.objects.filter(fecha=fecha,archivo=each).exists():
    Callgate_Syni.objects.create(fecha=fecha,archivo=each)
os.system('/home/pyc/DjangoProjects/tap_app/media/docs/callgate/envia.sh')
...
```

Comment: I already have a date flag ("fecha" is date in spanish). I use this 'fecha = datetime.date.today()' as flag and to manage all the files uploaded in a specific date. But always save the record. If the record is already saved I don't need to update the database only not save the information about an already uploaded file

Comment: @joselegit I have edited my answer for your solution. Hope I understand you correctly.

Comment: You don't need to insert files in the same date even if they are different?

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on filenames, but on its content, so one idea is using hash function. Therefore one solution is:

1. Add hash field to your file model.
2. When a file is uploaded calculate hash of its content, without the name, so that it won't affect the resulting hash.
3. Save file to disk, and its hash to DB.
4. When user uploads another file calculate its hash and see if there's a record with the same hash in DB.

   a. If no go to step 3.

   b. If yes do nothing.

The drawback calculating hash requires resources, but it's more reliable then just filename.